# c# timespan two dates linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i have this table

```
            Starting Time Ending Time Charges
1   True    09:00:00    17:00:00    500.00  
2   True    17:01:00    18:00:00    1000.00 
3   True    18:01:00    08:59:00    2000.00
```

Basically the above table is determining the charges that will be printed on the delivery order based on the time .if the person comes on the window to collect the delivery order at 4:00pm the charges will be 500. if he comes after 6:00pm , the charges will be 2000 .

Previously it was working fine as the final Ending time was 11:59pm. but some cases of 2:am was also reported so i have to change the last time to 8:59 am. now the thing is not working

I cannot make this query work in the above scenario now when the last ending time was changed to 8:59am from 11:59pm. `ts` is the current time i.e system.datetime.now

```
 db.JobDoDeliveryTimeSlots.FirstOrDefault(m => ts >= m.StartingTime && ts <= m.EndingTime && m.isOrginal == false);
```

Comment: What is the variable `ts`? can you post is assignment and declaration?

Comment: System.datetime.now()

Comment: but it's correct!? you don't use any dates..

Comment: Since you can span over more than one day you should save DateTime and not only Time. In facts your code is just right.

Comment: For some reason unkown to me if i login to the form at 1:00 am. no record is selected

Comment: You haven't stated what the columns are in the table, or what you're trying to achieve. The question is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: can you write what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: you should be sleeping at 1am :)  anyway you should probably use DateTime.TimeofDay instead since the date part  of the dates will mess things up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Thorarins on the contrary, I would suggest keeping proper `DateTimeOffset` values in the database, then comparison with any other date and time combination will work even spanning multiple days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is handle the date rollover, use something like this:

```
db.JobDoDeliveryTimeSlots.FirstOrDefault(m => m.isOrginal == false 
    && (m.EndingTime < m.StartingTime 
       ? ts >= m.StartingTime || ts <= m.EndingTime
       : ts >= m.StartingTime && ts <= m.EndingTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ending time is greater than the starting time then are you assuming it to be the day after?  If so then perhaps try something like this, where I add a day to the ending time if it is less than the starting time:

`db.JobDoDeliveryTimeSlots.FirstOrDefault(m =>
    ts >= m.StartingTime
 && ts <= ((m.EndingTime >= m.StartingTime) ? m.EndingTime : m.EndingTime.AddDays(1))
 && m.isOrginal == false);`

Comment: Just to tidy this up a little bit, perhaps consider adding the day when you're reading in the data, rather than adding it for each query.  That would be computationally cheaper, and you wouldn't have to remember to do it for every query that you wrote.